# Maximum $x$ value for error in Taylor polynomial.

Tags: calculus

For the function $f(x) = x \cdot \ln(x)$, with a Taylor polynomial of degree $4$ centred around $a = 1$, I'm trying to find the largest value of $x$, where $x > 1$ such that the error $|E(x)|$ is guaranteed to be less than $ 10^{-4}$. If I've done the maths right the error function works out to be $\frac{-6 \cdot (x-1)^5}{z^4\cdot5!}$. where $z$ lies between $x$ and $a$

However I'm unsure how to apply this to find the maximum value of $x$, any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Comment: The denominator should just be $5!$.

Comment: the z should just be to the 4th power, not -4, sorry

Comment: You should use the Lagrange error bound instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Lagrange error bound instead.

Since the radius of convergence is $1$, the interval of convergence is $0 < x < 2$, Choosing $x=2$ gives the maximum value of the range as $2 \ln 2$.

Then we have to solve the inequality:
$$\left| \frac{2 \ln2\cdot (x-1)^{4+1}}{(4+1)!} \right| < 0.0001$$
$$\left| (x-1)^5 \right| < \frac{0.006}{\ln2}$$

and I get that the maximum value of $x$ is around $1.387$.

With the actual polynomial, the maximum value of $x$ is around $1.483$. However, there is no way to possibly know this with the standard methods.

Comment: thankyou so much for your help

Comment: No problem. Actually, you can use $f^{(5)} (z)$ in this problem, but doing this will give you a lower maximum value.